# Create valid h264 from partial stream of h264 video data and wrap as Mp4

Tags: node.js, video-streaming, video-processing, h.264

Lets say that I am reading from data stream, and that stream is sending the content of an h264 video feed. Given I read from that stream and I have some amount of data consisting of an indeterminate number of frames (NAL?). Given that i know the framerate, and size of the originating video, how would I go about converting this snippet into a mp4 that i could view? The video does not contain audio.

I want to do this using nodejs? My attempts to do so have produced nothing resembling a valid h264 file to convert into mp4. My thoughts so far were to strip any data preceding the first found start code in the data and feed that into a file and use ffmpeg (currently just testing in the command line) to convert the file to mp4.

What's the correct way to go about doing this?

ie. something like this (it's in Typescript but same thing)

```
//We assume here that when this while loop exist at least one full frame of data will have been read and written to disk
let stream: WriteStream = fs.createWriteStream("./test.h264")
while(someDataStream.available()) { //just an example not real code
    let data: Buffer = someDataStream.readSomeData() //just an example not a real method call
    let file = null;
    try {
        file = fs.statSync("./test.h264");
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
    }

    if(!stream.writable) {
        console.error("stream not writable")
    } else if(file == null || file.size <= 0) {
      

        let index = data.indexOf(0x7C)
        console.log("index: " + index)
        if(index > 0) {
            console.log("index2: " + data.slice(index).indexOf(0x7c))
            stream.write(data.slice(index))
        }
    } else {
        stream.write(data)
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is quite apparent, I'm  asking how to go about doing what's described above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle a data stream, you'll need to emit fragmented MP4. Like all [MP4](https://www.w3.org/2013/12/byte-stream-format-registry/isobmff-byte-stream-format.html#iso-media-segments), fMP4 streams begin with a preamble containing ftyp, moov, and styp boxes. Then each frame is encoded with a moof / mdat box pair.

In order to generate a useful preamble from your H.264 bitstream, you need to locate a SPS / PPS pair of NALUs in the H264 data, to set up the avc1 box within the moov box. Those two NALUs are often immediately followed by an I-frame (a key frame).  The first frame in a stream must be an I-frame, and subsequent ones can be P- or B- frames. E

It's a fairly complex task involving lots of bit-banging and buffer-shuffling (those are technical terms ;-).

I've been working on a piece of [js code](https://github.com/OllieJones/webm2mp4-js) to extract H.264 from webm and put it into fmp4. It's not yet complete.  It's backed up by another piece of [code](https://github.com/OllieJones/h264-interp-utils) to decode the parts of the H264 stream that are needed to pack it properly into fMP4.

I wish I could write, "here are the ten lines of code you need" but those formats (fMP4 and H264) aren't simple enough to make that possible.

Comment: Do you think it would be easier if the source was pre wrapped as an MP4?

Comment: If you already have the beginning of an fMP4 stream, you can leave out sequences of frames, as long as the first frame sequence you retain starts with an I-frame (key frame). But if you don't have the fMP4 preamble (ftyp, moov, styp) you'll have to reconstruct them. That's where the coding gets tricky.

Comment: might be a little cringe worthy but i ended up stripping the SPS / PPS pair of NALUs in the H264 data from a different file (made using the exact same hardware/software so they should be identical anyhow) and prepended those onto the first valid NALU i could find in the stream and then converted it to mp4

Answer (score 0):

Idk why none of those questions doesn't actually have an easy answer. Here you go, Node.js solution, `i` argument just in case you need to offset the search

```
const soi = Buffer.from([0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01]);
function findStartFrame(buffer, i = -1) {
    while ((i = buffer.indexOf(soi, i + 1)) !== -1) {
        if ((buffer[i + 4] & 0x1F) === 7) return i
    }
    return -1
}
```

Comment: Because this was an information ask not a do it for me ask, as well as the previous answer having already provided that information

Comment: If you want someone to do it for you then ask your own question. The information to write your own code is here with some minor additional googling. I dont support just spoon feeding people code snippets that they dont understand and dont want that for myself either.

Comment: Also the code you posted is not enough to make that work properly at all...

Comment: It is enough to feed that piece to ffmpeg with option -c:v copy to get result in 70ms so I consider that enough. I'm not into "bit-banging and buffer-shuffling" tbh, so it's just the code that does enough for it to be possible.

Comment: Feeding into ffmeg was not the point of the question...  It's bot valid if you still have to feed it in for additional processing.